# How to send Array through URL using Http Utility so that is comes out properly formatted?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

In my razor view I have an array called 'array1' and I want to send it through URL. For that purpose I'm using HttpUtility.UrlEncode helper method.

```
int[] array1= Model.MovieIds.ToArray(); //(values of this array are 1,2,3,4,5,6)

     <a class="btn btn-default" href="/Movies/Genres/?page=@start&Ids=@HttpUtility.UrlEncode(string.Join(",",array1))">@start</a>
```

But the problem is that string in the URL is not formatted properly. What I'm trying to achieve is this `Ids=1,2,3,4,5,6` , but this is the URL result that I get:

```
Ids=1%2c2%2c3%2c4%2c5%2c6
```

Comment: `%2c` is `,`. I don't see any problem

Comment: I am sure someone will answer this but please dont do this. Find another way.

Comment: @L.B Ok, but do you know is there any way to format it properly (Like 1,2,3,4,5,6)?

Comment: @Mike don't use `HttpUtility.UrlEncode` :)

Comment: I wish it was that simple, I really need this to work as it is. :)

Comment: @L.B may I ask why not using `HttpUtility.UrlEncode`?

Comment: OK, I just realized that there is no need for me to do this, because in controller method string gets converted to 1,2,3,4,5. :)

Comment: @Mike, Lesson: test/debug people's comments before replying it with your current knowledge

Comment: Yeah you’re right, I didnt realize that your first comment was actually the answer i needed, sorry. :-)